# How to start and shutdown computer at a given time

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, window

I want to start and shutdown at some given time.
For example if I want to shutdown after 1 hour then I can simply right click then create a shortuct and  type `shutdown -s -t 3600` then my computer will shutdown after 1 hour.Is there any way to wake up from sleep mode or restart computer or simply start the computer using batch scripting or like the way I am doing to shutdown or any other way?

**Note** I dont want to use powershell

Comment: What's wrong with PowerShell? Allergic?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 how can one be allergic to computer codes?

Comment: I suggest you may be allergic because "I don't want to use PowerShell" seems like a very arbitrary limit to impose... :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am describing in brief.I have to 2 system one is server and it has public ip and another is only connected to LAN but no internet.My requirement is to start/turn off the computer(the computer which is not connected to internet) I am successful in shutting down.But dont know how to start.So I dont want to use power shell

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 dont you think the linked question has not got any answer to start the computer?

Comment: The answers don't make it a different _question_.  If you'd like newer/different answers to an existing question, feel free to place a [bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it.  Anyhow, the existing answers do mention ways to wake it (WOL, BIOS wake timers).  Plus I just stuck an answer on it explaining how you can wake the computer via Task Scheduler (I was surprised it wasn't mentioned already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line (so you can enter a time and make a batch file)
For example:
-m \Computer   Specifies a specific computer on the network that you want to shut down or reboot. Absent this parameter, the command affects only the local PC on which it is run.

For shutdown: shutdown -s -t 00

For restart: (the -r parameter is for when to restart)

c:\windows\system32\shutdown -r -t 00

So you can have two batch files. One for shutdown and one for restart. The batch file for shutdown would call the restart file right before it runs. You would use a delay command in the shutdown file like SLEEP PAUSE or TIMEOUT.

Here are all the parameters:
http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/shut-down-and-reboot-remote-pc/

Comment: Thanks but I dont want a schduler,And I know how to shutdown.Just want to know how to startIf you can tell me how to start using scheduler then also you are welcome

Comment: I edited my answer. See the new option 1.

Comment: can you tell me how to start?

Comment: I don't see how these answers provide the ability to START a computer at a certain time.

Comment: It's in the commands list. I added it to my answer.

Comment: the instructions I'm reading show how to shutdown a computer at a given time.  that is the opposite of starting.

Comment: Adding the -r parameter will tell it when to restart

Comment: now, you are mistaken.  shutdown -r will cause a reboot (aka re-start).  This is not the same as starting the computer.  for instance:  now, power off your machine, ie; shutdown -now ... go to lunch.  come back and press the power button.  that is "starting a computer."

Comment: When you click it, it will shutdown and then restart at the given time. Are you saying that you want to click and have it say shutdown in an hour and then reboot in 2 hours?

Comment: @Zvi, you have now correctly understood his question.

Comment: Ok, so then you would need two batch scripts where one would call the other. I'll update the answer.